# Drill query hbase including TIMERANGE

Tags: timestamp, hbase, version, apache-drill

In hbase shell we could use command like

`get '/test/service','rk1',{COLUMN=>'fm1:col1',TIMERAGE=>[0,TS1]}`

to query the record versions fall into `[0,TS1)` where `TS1` is the timestamp for each version (the ts1 we set when running the 'put' command).

Is there a way to do the same SQL query in Drill to query such data?

e.g. `` select * from hbase.`/test/table` as t where t.fm1.TIMESTAMP = 1442XXXXX ``

Comment: Have u tried this query on HBase using drill ?

Comment: It would be better if u can add plugin details and errors after querying

Comment: I am currently using the Drill Hbase Plugin, but there are no errors, just say result not found since  `t.fm1.TIMESTAMP` is considered as a field for fm1 instead of the real timestamp

Comment: can you  write output of `get '/test/service','rk1',{COLUMN=>'fm1:col1',TIMERAGE=>[0,TS1]}`

Comment: `hbase(main):005:0> get '/test/service','key1',{COLUMN=>'fm1:col1',TIMERANGE=>[0,1441116713770]}`

`COLUMN                CELL  ` 
                                                   
 `fm1:col1  timestamp=1441116713761, value=1441116713768              
 me`                                                                             
`1 row(s) in 0.0040 seconds`

Comment: able to query like  where t.fm1:col1= xxxxxx  but  t.fm1:col1.TIMESTAMP is not giving results.